# How to use gsl::span in c++ linux env?

Tags: c++, gsl

What is the alternative way to use `gsl::span`
Example:

`auto const givenName{::gsl::span<char const* const>(array, arraySize)};`

how can I replace the `::gsl::span`?

Comment: Just by the name I would say C++20’s `std::span`

Comment: @Daniel, what about c++14 standard?

Comment: Seeing you mention the linux env, I'm guessing you don't want to use the Microsoft GSL implementation. There is [gsl lite](https://github.com/gsl-lite/gsl-lite) which is cross platform and includes GSL has to offer, `gsl::span` is one of them

Comment: I don't understand why you bring `std::next` into this. It'll be useful to know what your actual goal is. The one a `span` accomplishes, because just "replacing it" isn't a very clear and useful goal. Then we may be able to comment on how to attain that goal with other means.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For older standards, a span polyfill like https://github.com/tcbrindle/span